# Rider can't access git project

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, rider

I'm doing a project with a friend, he created a repository for himself and gave me all the rights. Through Git Hub Desktop I calmly create branches, commits, push them, etc., but Rider, when trying to push a commit, will throw an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWJRN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omtkj.png)

He is trying to access this project through my account, but the project is on a friend's account. Tell me how to fix this?

At the request of Rider, I added my GIT account, but this did not help
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQO91.png)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCb3K.png)]

Comment: It seems that you're not properly logged in... Check _File | Settings | Version Control | GitHub_ in Rider. Furthermore, execute `git push` from a shell of your choice. And please prefer pasting nicely formatted text over images